# min_by in a hashmap within a group of values in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a hashmap in the below form:

```
{1=>[a, b, 3], 2=>[a, c, 5], 3=>[a, d, 1], 4=>[a, e, 4], 5=>[f, g, 2]}...
```

i need the minimum number of the third value in each key value pair, but with in the group of same first value. for example in the above hashmap, there are four key value pairs with the first value as 'a', i need to retrieve the minimum of the third value for which the first value is 'a', i.e., 1

I tried `hash.min_by{|k, v|, v[2]}`, and obviously it gave me the minimum in the map. How i do get the minimum with the group of 'a's?

Comment: Just add `v[0] == "a" && v[2]` to `min_by` instead.

Comment: @squiguy it is not working, showing me 'each' comparison of flaseclass error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hash.values.select {|a| a[0] == 'a'}.map {|a| a[2]}.min
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a mapping of all of the groupings you can use:

```
hash.values.each_with_object(Hash.new) do |(group_by, _, v), min_map|
  current_min = min_man[group_by] ||= v  
  min_map[group_by] = v if v < current_min  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h = {1=>['a', 'b', 3], 2=>['a', 'c', 5], 3=>['a','d', 1], 4=>['a', 'e', 4], 5=>['f', 'g', 2]} #=>1
h.map{|k,v| v.last if v[0] == 'a' }.compact.min #=>1
```