# need a value from hashmap based on minimum value within a group in ruby

Tags: ruby

This is a follow up question on [min_by in a hashmap within a group of values in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703993/min-by-in-a-hashmap-within-a-group-of-values-in-ruby).

I have a hashmap as below

```
{1=>[a, b, 3], 2=>[a, c, 5], 3=>[a, d, 1], 4=>[a, e, 4], 5=>[f, g, 2]}...
```

i need the minimum number of the third value in each key value pair and and the second value of the array for which the minimum was found.
I tried

`hash.values.select {|a,b,c| a[0] == 'a'}.map {|a| a[2]}.min`

but it did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
h = {1=>[:a, :b, 3], 2=>[:a, :c, 5], 3=>[:a, :d, 1], 4=>[:a, :e, 4], 5=>[:f, :g, 2]}
h.min_by { |k, v| v[2] }[1][1..2]
# => [:d, 1]

# Only values having :a as first element
h.select{ |k,v| :a == v[0] }.min_by { |k, v| v[2] }[1][1..2]
# => [:d, 1]
```

In both examples change `[1..2]` into `[1]` if you want to get just `:d` instead of `[:d, 1]`.

Comment: it is not right! :) he wants only key/value pair for in which value `:a` present.

Answer (score 1):

```
h = {1=>['a', 'b', 3], 2=>['a', 'c', 5], 3=>['a','d', 1], 4=>['a', 'e', 4], 5=>['f', 'g', 2]} 
h.select {|k,v| v[0] == 'a' }.min_by{|k,v| v.last}.last[-2..-1]
```